# Android Broken Navigation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, authentication

I am getting a weird navigation behavior and I don't know why it's happening neither how to fix it.

I just created a new project in Android Studio 2.1 and added a `Login Activity` and a `Master/Detail Flow Activity` from the Activity Gallery.

I added the following code inside `attemptLogin()` into the `LoginActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This way, the app opens in a `Login Activity` and when I click the `Sign In` button, it jumps to the `Master/Detail Flow Activity`....so far, so good....BUT, when I click the back home button on the `Master/Detail Flow Activity` toolbar, the app closes, it doesn't go back to the `Login Activity`, as expected.

The `Master/Detail Flow Activity` works as expected though, if I click an item, a new `Activity` opens with the item's details, and it's back button works as expected, bringing the app back to the `List Activity`.

I can't find any code in the `Login Activity` or the `Master/Detail Flow Activity` that would change the back stack, I even added a second `Login Activity`, making the app go:

`Login Activity 1` -> `Login Activity 2` -> `Master/Detail Flow Activity`

It works as expected now between `Login Activity 1` and `Login Activity 2` but when I try to go back from `Master/Detail Flow Activity`, instead of going back to `Login Activity 2`, it closes the app...and I can't find any code in `Master/Detail Flow Activity` either that would change the back stack. My `AndroidManifest` is also as it should be (and it was generated automagically by Android Studio, I didn't change anything).

I even tried to do a:

`Login Activity 1` -> `Login Activity 2` -> `Master/Detail Flow Activity 1` -> `Master/Detail Flow Activity 2`

And the error still exists between `Login Activity 2 -> Master/Detail Flow Activity 1`...but it works as expected between `Master/Detail Flow Activity 1 -> Master/Detail Flow Activity 2` and `Login Activity 1 -> Login Activity 2`...so again, no clues there, and this became really weird, since this test shows it's not on the `Login Activity` calling of the new `Activity` and neither in the `Master/Detail Flow Activity` reception, but only in the interface between these two particular `Activities`.

This is fairly easy fro anyone to try and reproduce, just create a new project and create the `Activities` as I said. **What can I do to go back to the `Login Activity`? Why is this happening?**

---

EDIT:

Full code for testing [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzcaluqXbeOrWTdqZnR0bFVtZ2M)

Comment: Best approach: First debug the code with breakpoints, if not found any bug then Post your code..

Comment: I debugged it all... The code it's too big to post, it's easier to create it yourself on Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because in your inner class UserLoginTask, that its inside the LoginActivity class, you are calling **finish()** inside the **onPostExecute()** method. Remove this line and you will notice that the app is working good. 
So it would be like this:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
          mAuthTask = null;
          showProgress(false);

          if (!success) {
              mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
              mPasswordView.requestFocus();
          }
      }
```

I tested and its working as expected!

Comment: I feel silly right now...I searched for all `finish` and `navigateUpFromSameTask`, I guess I missed this! Thanks! Just one thing I don't get....why does it go back from `LoginActivity2` to `LoginActivity` if both have been finished then?

Comment: No, an activity is finished if you explicit finish(). Please mark this answer as correct if it works well for you

Comment: I got it....I can go back and forth between the activities because I am doing it fast...less than 2 seconds, which is the background task delay...so as far as I navigate within 2 seconds, all works.....all makes sense now! Thanks!